# Can the string "abcedf" be matched to string "bafcde" in a single line command?

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I am planning to implement an indexing structure in my program. For example, if I have *100 rows* in the table, I will number these rows from 1 to 100 in another column by appending an `_` to the end of the number.(`1_,2_,3_ etc` so that each number can be identified uniquely).

After processing the rows, I am storing the output into a file.

For example, I insert the line `1_,2_,4_,5_` into a file.

if I get a value as `5_,2_,1_,4_` or `2_,5_,1_,4_`, I should not insert those values.

An implementation that comes to my mind is, to sort the numbers and then compare them. However, if the total rows becomes 100,000 it won't be a good solution. Is it possible as a single line command in `perl` script or `awk` or `sed`?

**EDIT**:

To be more precise and short, for a set of unique and distinct values, how can I find all the combinations without repetitions?

**Example**:

If I have 3 unique keys `1,2 and 3`, how can I find all combinations without the same combination repeated twice?

So for the above example, we can find a combination as,

```
123
```

Now, when I search for `213` or `321` it should give me a match as I already have the combination `123` obtained.

Comment: If we are talking about 100,000 whatever then shells should not be used anyway.

Comment: You seem to have conflated having a single line solution with having a performant solution. In fact, probably the opposite is true.

Comment: I would suggest a c program for this. It takes a little longer to write, but it will be a one word command when it's done =)

Comment: This is awfully inefficient! Why do you need to generate an index file like that? Why not BST, AVL & other options?

Comment: @slm, let me know if this looks fine or needs more edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could setup a SQLite database and perform SQL selects from that, which would probably be cleaner to implement and would set you up for being more portable later on.

But here's a rough idea. Say I have 2 files:

```
$ more index.txt new_vals.txt 
::::::::::::::
index.txt
::::::::::::::
1_,2_,4_,5_
::::::::::::::
new_vals.txt
::::::::::::::
5_,2_,1_,4
2_,5_,1_,4
```

With this command we can match:

```
$ for i in $(<new_vals.txt); do nums=${i//_,/}; \
        grep -oE "[${nums}_,]+" index.txt; done
1_,2_,4_,5_
1_,2_,4_,5_
```

This demonstrates that we can match each line from `new_vals.txt` to an existing line in `index.txt`.

#### UPDATE #1

Based on the OP's edit the following would do what he wants using a modification of the above approach.

```
$ for i in $(<new_vals.txt); do 
  nums=${i//_,/} 

  printf "# to check: [%s]" $i
  k=$(grep -oE "[${nums}_,]+" index.txt | grep "[[:digit:]]_$")
  printf " ==> match: [%s]\n" $k

done
```

With a modified version of test data:

```
$ more index.txt new_vals.txt 
::::::::::::::
index.txt
::::::::::::::
1_,2_,4_,5_
0_,2_,3_,9_
::::::::::::::
new_vals.txt
::::::::::::::
5_,2_,1_,4_
2_,5_,1_,4_
1_,1_,1_,1_
1_,2_,4_,4_
```

Now when we run the above (put inside a script for simplicity, `parser.bash`):

```
$ ./parser.bash 
# to check: [5_,2_,1_,4_] ==> match: [1_,2_,4_,5_]
# to check: [2_,5_,1_,4_] ==> match: [1_,2_,4_,5_]
# to check: [1_,1_,1_,1_] ==> match: []
# to check: [1_,2_,4_,4_] ==> match: []
```

#### How it works

The above method works by exploiting some key characteristics exhibited by the nature of your data. For example. Only matches will end with a digit followed by a underscore. The `grep "[[:digit:]]_$"` picks only these results out.

The other part of the script, `grep -oE "[${nums}_,]+" index.txt` will pick out lines that contain characters from strings in the file `new_vals.txt` which match strings from `index.txt`.

#### Additional adjustments

If the nature of the data is such that strings may be variable in length then the 2nd grep will need to be expanded to guarantee that we're only picking out strings that are of sufficient length. There are several ways to accomplish this, either by expanding the pattern or by making use of a counter, perhaps using `wc` or some other means, that would confirm that the matches are of a certain type.

Expanding it like so:

```
k=$(grep -oE "[${nums}_,]+" index.txt | \
    grep "[[:digit:]]_,[[:digit:]]_,[[:digit:]]_,[[:digit:]]_$")
```

Would allow for the elimination of strings like this:

```
$ ./parser2.bash 
# to check: [5_,2_,1_,4_] ==> match: [1_,2_,4_,5_]
# to check: [2_,5_,1_,4_] ==> match: [1_,2_,4_,5_]
# to check: [1_,1_,1_,1_] ==> match: []
# to check: [1_,2_,4_,4_] ==> match: []
# to check: [1_,2_,5_] ==> match: []
```

Comment: This seems a good solution. But I might have 1000s of rows and at that time the command might become too much of overhead to get executed.

Comment: @Ramesh - maybe, looping though this isn't that burdensome to a fairly modern system. Can you show more of the actual indexes? I wasn't 100% sure about your full syntax, what I'm showing is rough, in my mind, so I'm not sure how robust it will end up being. I'm not so concerned w/ performance, but more how tolerant this approach would end up being.

Comment: I have not actually implemented it. It is just an idea that I have in my mind. I thought if I use (_) for each number, it would be a better approach to have unique indices. However, I need to think more of this approach before I can explain more about the indices.

Comment: @Ramesh - my first reaction was that the `_,` was a bad idea. I would need o understand better what you're actual goal is. It feels like you're over complicating something.

Comment: can you please come in chat? I would try and explain the problem

Comment: @Ramesh - I can't tonight, I'm actually working. Was taking a break and answering your Q.

Comment: Oh sorry. No problem. I will try to think bit more and make the problem more clearer to understand and hopefully to implement. :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't putting the sequence `123` in a character class in `grep` like so: `[123,_]` allow it to match number sequences which are not permutations of `1_,2_,3_` (such as `1_,1_,2_`)?

Comment: that solution would match 1_,1_,1_,1_,1_

Comment: @Emmanuel - fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Finding uniques is a piece of cake with `sed`:

```
{ 
echo identical identical
echo not_so_much as_before
echo abcdef bafcde
} | sed ':u;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\2/;tu'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
nto_much abfr
```

Not really sure how to represent this correctly in *Markdown*, but the output from the above command is actually a newline and the single space that separated the two strings, then the above, then another newline and space.

The `t` `sed` function is a fully portable device [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) so:

> [`2addr`]`t` [`label`] Test.
>
> Branch to the `:` command verb bearing the `label` if any substitutions have been made since the most recent reading of an input line or execution of a `t`. If `label` is not specified, branch to the end of the script.

Let's watch it as it works, I'll add a `p`rint in just the right place:

```
{ 
echo identical identical
echo not_so_much as_before
echo abcdef bafcde
} | sed ':u;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\2/p;tu'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
dentical identcal
entical ientcal
ntical intcal
tical itcal
ical ical
cal cal
al al
l l


nt_so_much as_befre
ntso_much asbefre
nto_much abefre
nto_much abfr
nto_much abfr
bcdef bfcde
cdef fcde
def fde
ef fe
f f
```

You can see there is a differing amount of empty space between the three different `t`ests. This is a result of the order in which `sed` negates the characters, which means that `whitespaces` are also negated, so long as there is an even number of them.

The command:

```
sed ':u;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\2/;tu'
```

`s/`elects the first `\(.`character`\)` on a line that can possibly be selected `\1`twice, *and* `\(.`all`*\)` characters between the two. It then `/`replaces`/` the entire selection with *only* the `\2`selection between them. `:`Rinse, repea`t`.

### OPTIMIZE IT!

We can improve the performance of this function by a ***very large margin*** with the simple addition of only two more characters in the command, just so:

```
{ 
echo identical identical
echo not_so_much as_before
echo abcdef bafcde
} | sed ':u;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\1/\2/p;tu'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
nt_so_much as_befre
ntso_much asbefre
nto_much abefre
nto_much abfr
nto_much abfr
bcdef bfcde
cdef fcde
f f
```

`sed` now performs negations on any *sequence* of 1 or more characters that can be twice selected, which is why *identical* makes no appearance in  the above - it is completely negated on the first pass.

And without `p`rint the results are the same:

```
{
echo identical identical
echo about_as_much as_before
echo abcdef bafcde
} | sed ':u;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\1/\2/;tu'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
ta_mch fr
```

### POSITIVE FROM NEGATIVE

It requires very little else - and no more recursion - to negate the negation.

```
{
echo identical identical
echo not_so_much as_before
echo abcdef bafcde
} | sed 'h;:u;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\1/\2/;tu
    / ./{H;g;
    s/^/NOT FULL MATCH:\t/
    s/\n/\n\t%:\t/;b}
    g;s/^/FULL MATCH:\t/'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
FULL MATCH:     identical identical
NOT FULL MATCH: not_so_much as_before
        %:      nto_much abfr
FULL MATCH:     abcdef bafcde
```

Or even just:

```
{
echo identical identical
echo not_so_much as_before
echo abcdef bafcde
} | sed -e ':u;s/\(..*\)\(.*\)\1/\2/;tu' \
    -e '/ ./{cshite...' -e 'b};cHOORAY!'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
HOORAY!
shite...
HOORAY!
```

Comment: really impress by this simplicity but it work on known fixed pattern, in this case you could have 12545_ and 545_ where only 12 differ (and that could be on a later or sooner 1254_).

Answer (score 1):

For the concept using shell tools sed/grep
    ExistingSeq='8_,1_,2_,3_,4_,5_,9_,7_,6_'

```
NewSeq="5_,2_,1_,4_"

# prepa
SizeTemp=$( echo "${NewSeq}" | sed -e 's/[^,]//g;s/^/,/' )
Size=${#SizeTemp}
echo "${NewSeq}" | sed -e 's/,/\
,/g;s/^/,/' > /tmp/ToFind

# search
InsideOcc=$( echo "${ExistingSeq}" | sed -e 's/,/\
,/g' | egrep -c -f /tmp/ToFind )

# test
echo "test with an if on 'InsideOcc' [${InsideOcc}] is lower (not present) or equivalent (present) to Size: [${Size}] "

rm /tmp/ToFind
```

to be efficient and avoid lot of similar sed, work with (temporary ) index file with one element per line.

Now, this is not a good way to create huge file index especially due to exponential time requested on sequence length and index length. AWK is certainly faster in a one occurence of tools test per sequence and only memory  (no temp file that eat time to manage)

Comment: In every comparison I've ever seen, `sed` outperforms `awk.` I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: on simple operation sed could be faster but often awk is really faster. awk is an evolution of sed. On which test do you see awk slower ?

Comment: Often `awk` is faster at what? And how is it any operation a computer performs is not a simple one? It cant count any higher than one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another technique: create a "key" from a string by sorting its characters:

```
gawk '
    function generate_key(s,  n,a,i,s2) {
        if (s in cached) return cached[s]
        n = split(s, a, //)
        asort(a)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) s2 = s2 a[i]
        cached[s] = s2
        return s2
    }
    {
        key = generate_key($1)
        status = (key in seen) ? "no" : "yes"
        print $1, key, status
        seen[key]++
    }
' OFS="\t" <<END
123
231
321
312
1_,2_,4_,5_
5_,2_,1_,4_
2_,5_,1_,4_
END
```

```
123 123 yes
231 123 no
321 123 no
312 123 no
1_,2_,4_,5_ 1245,,,____ yes
5_,2_,1_,4_ 1245,,,____ no
2_,5_,1_,4_ 1245,,,____ no
```

Answer (score 0):

if indexfile is composed only of lines of 6 characters.
This will match any combination of "abcdef" in indexfile

```
grep a indexfile | grep b | grep c | grep d |grep e | grep f
```

if indexfile is more complicated use sed to extract the indexes.