# Remove duplicates values within a field

Tags: awk

How to remove duplicate (or more) values within a selected field in a file, keeping only one copy?

Exemple

Input file:

```
A    1,2,3,45,1,8,2,3
B    5,6,6,6,6,6,2,3,7
```

Expected output:

```
A    1,2,3,45,8
B    5,6,2,3,7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `perl` solution:

```
perl -anle '                                                                    
    print "$F[0] ", join ",", grep {!$seen{$_}++} split ",",$F[1];              
    %seen=();                                                                   
' file
A 1,2,3,45,8
B 5,6,2,3,7
```

Answer (score 5):

A `sed` one:

```
sed '
  s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/,&,/g;:1
  s/\(\(,[^,[:blank:]]*\)\(,[^,[:blank:]]*\)*\)\2,/\1,/;t1
  s/,\([^[:blank:]]*\),/\1/g'
```

(it processes all the fields that contain `,` characters and preserves spacing)

Comment: why didn't I notice this 17 hours ago?

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -pe 's{\S*,\S*}{join ",", uniq split ",", $&}ge'
```

(it processes all the fields that contain `,` characters and preserves spacing)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is like Stephane's though it is a little different. Anyway, I took the trouble to write it. I based it on this thing I did before [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128707/52934) *(where I also explain it a lot better)*...

```
sed ':t
s/\([^,]*\),\(.*\1\)/ \2/;tt
s/  */,/g;s/,/ /;s/,$//' <<\DATA
A 1,2,3,45,1,8,2,3,
B 5,6,6,6,6,6,2,3,7
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
A 45,1,8,2,3
B 5,6,2,3,7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{n=split($2, a, ","); $2=a[1];
  for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {$2 = ($2 ~ "(^|,)" a[i] "($|,)") ? $2 : ($2 "," a[i])}}1' OFS='\t' file
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a solution in `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[ \t,]+";
    OFS = ",";
}

{
    delete seen;
    for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if($i in seen) {
            $i = "";
        }
        seen[$i] = 1;
    }
    sub(",","\t");   #separate first field with a tab
    gsub(",,+",","); #squeeze empty fields
    sub(",$","");    #remove trailing comma, if any
    print;
}
```